# Ansible Loop & Array

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I need to loop a list of names to use it in the query itself. Upon looping, I want to gather the information from the query itself and store it in an array. I manage to store it in an array but whenever I re-run the program, it will keep adding the same value again and again.

My data:

```yaml
    priv: [admin, monitor]
    data:
      - {name: admin, locked: 'no', uid: 0}
      - {name: monitor, locked: 'no', uid: 102}
```

This is my code:

```yaml
    - name: Test Informationk 
      set_fact: 
        info2: "{{ data|json_query(jmesquery) + info2|default([]) }}"
        cacheable: yes
      vars: 
        jmesquery: "[?name=='{{ item }}'].[name,locked,uid]"
      loop: "{{ priv }}"
```

This is my output:

```yaml
    - - monitor
        'no'
        102
    - - admin
        'no'
        0
    - - monitor
        'no'
        102
    - - admin
        'no'
        0
    - - monitor
        'no'
        102
    - - admin
        'no'
        0
```

It will keep adding and adding every time I re-run the program. The existing data is supposed to be only 2 items.

Comment: Please see [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask), [mcve](/help/mcve) and [x/y problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @Zeitounator, FYI, the problem is clear, despite the fact the [mre] is missing. The question should be improved though. You're right. I only want to say that it's not necessary to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: *"**Whenever I re-run the program, it will keep adding the same value again and again.**"*

A: You set `cacheable: yes`. Quoting from [cacheable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html#parameter-cacheable):

> This actually creates 2 copies of the variable, a normal 'set_fact' host variable with high precedence and a lower **'ansible_fact' one that is available for persistence via the facts cache plugin**.

If you don't want to cache the variable disable it. If you want to see in detail what's going on put a debug in front of the *set_fact*, for example, the playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    priv: [admin, monitor]
    data:
      - {name: admin, locked: 'no', uid: 0}
      - {name: monitor, locked: 'no', uid: 102}
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: info2
    - set_fact:
        info2: "{{ data|json_query(jmesquery) + info2|default([]) }}"
        cacheable: false
      vars:
        jmesquery: "[?name=='{{ item }}'].[name,locked,uid]"
      loop: "{{ priv }}"
    - debug:
        var: info2
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  info2: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=admin)
ok: [localhost] => (item=monitor)

TASK [debug] *******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  info2:
  - - monitor
    - 'no'
    - 102
  - - admin
    - 'no'
    - 0
```

---

If you set both `cacheable: true` in *set_fact* and the configuration below (you must have already set the caching, I guess)

```
shell> cat ansible.cfg
[defaults]
fact_caching = jsonfile
fact_caching_connection = /tmp/ansible_cache.json

...
```

then you'll see the list incremented on each consecutive run of the playbook

```yaml
TASK [debug] ***************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  info2:
  - - monitor
    - 'no'
    - 102
  - - admin
    - 'no'
    - 0

TASK [set_fact] ***********************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=admin)
ok: [localhost] => (item=monitor)

TASK [debug] **************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  info2:
  - - monitor
    - 'no'
    - 102
  - - admin
    - 'no'
    - 0
  - - monitor
    - 'no'
    - 102
  - - admin
    - 'no'
    - 0
```

---

See the cache

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/ansible_cache.json/localhost 
{
    "info2": [
        [
            "monitor",
            "no",
            102
        ],
        [
            "admin",
            "no",
            0
        ]
    ]
}
```